# Can the mysql2 gem be used with a Postgres database in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am currently using a MySQL database and am considering moving to Postgres in the future. In my code I have:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "#{DB_HOST}", :username => "#{DB_USERNAME}",
:password => "#{DB_PASSWORD}", :database => "#{DB_NAME}")
sql = "SELECT /*complicated query with joins */ ASC"
data_setter = client.query(sql)
```

I am concerned that if I move to Postgres I will no longer be able to use the Mysql2 gem and perform queries similar to the code above.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They `mysql2` gem is `"A modern, simple and very fast Mysql library for Ruby - binding to libmysql"`. **No**, it won't work with a Postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same sort of thing but you'll have to switch to the [`pg` gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/frames) as Mysql2 only knows how to talk to MySQL. The interface is similar:

```
db  = PG::Connection.new(...)
sth = db.query('select /* big complicated pile of SQL */')
sth.each { |row| do_things_with_row(row) }
```

Generally you can go through ActiveRecord for most things (even raw SQL queries) but if you need to bypass all that and talk directly to the database then you can. You might have some issues with PostgreSQL not standing for the sort of sloppiness that MySQL will though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have been trying on and off over the past 4 days to implement my complicated join with ActiveRecord. I may need to use your pg gem example above if I can't pull it off, or start another question begging for help with ActiveRecord. Thanks again.

Comment: I tend to skip all the "helpful" ActiveRecord stuff for complicated queries and go straight to SQL, easier that way (for me at least).